# Алгоритм обхода в ширину не проходит проверку

Tags: python, алгоритм, олимпиада

**Задача:**

В неориентированном графе требуется найти длину кратчайшего пути между двумя вершинами.

*Входные данные*

Во входном файле INPUT.TXT записано сначала число N - количество вершин в графе (1 ≤ N ≤ 100). Затем записана матрица смежности (0 обозначает отсутствие ребра, 1 - наличие ребра). Затем записаны номера двух вершин - начальной и конечной.

*Выходные данные*

В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите длину кратчайшего пути. Если пути не существует, выведите одно число -1.

Ссылка на задание и там же проверяется: https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=127

**Пример:**
Ввод:

```
5
0 1 0 0 1
1 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
3 5
```

Вывод:

`3`

**Мой код:**

```
def search_width(n: int, start: int, end: int, dict_path: dict) -> int:
    from collections import deque
    if start == end or n == 1:
        return 0
    if start > end:
        start, end = end, start
    distation = [None] * (n + 1)
    queq = deque([start])
    distation[start] = 0
    while queq:
        x_point = queq.popleft()
        for i in dict_path[x_point]:
            if not distation[i]:
                distation[i] = distation[x_point] + 1
                queq.append(i)
    return distation[end] if distation[end] is not None else 1


n = int(input())
dict_path = {i: set() for i in range(1, n + 1)}
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    str_user = input().split()
    for num, j in enumerate(str_user, 1):
        if j == '1':
            dict_path[i].add(num)
            dict_path[num].add(i)
start, end = map(int, input().split())
print(search_width(n, start, end, dict_path))
```

**Проблема**

Основную часть тестов проходит, на 17 тесте выдаёт неправильный ответ.

Предположение: есть особый случай, к которому нужно добавить условие.

Ошибка в моём алгоритме или я не дописал случай?

Comment: просто что бросилось в глаза - `if start == end or n == 1:` тут наверное надо 0 вернуть?

Comment: Я пробовал 0, я согласен с вами насчёт этого. Исправил. Но тесты всё равно не проходят. Также на 17.

Comment: `return distation[end] if distation[end] is not None else 1` else -1?

Comment: Если пути не существует, выведите одно число -1

Comment: ну а вы 1 выводите, нет? (я просто питон не знаю)

Comment: для понимания, у вас выводится "один", а надо "минус один"

Comment: больше косяков не вижу, но я на питоне не пишу, и сам бы решал по другому немного =)

Comment: Я думал, типо тире и 1. Понял, тупой немного). Все тесты прошли

Comment:  класс, быстро разобрались ) Возвращать минус один если не найдно что то - такое часто встречается в задачах

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вцелом 2 проблемы в коде:

1. Если начало и конец совпадают, надо возвращать 0
2. Если путь не существует, то возвращаем -1 (минус один)

Также, как оптимизации:

1. Вам не нужно считать расстояния до всех вершин, можно только до вершины end
2. Вам не надо считать все пути до конца, как только встретили вершину end - можно прекращать поиск.